# How to click this specific button with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, class, button

Newbie for js, I'm searching and trying to piece up a code. But I got trouble clicking a button. (http://new.cloudfile.co/transfer At lowerhand there's this big orange + button) 
I found a method for this

```
var tmp2=document.getElementsByClassName('...').item(...);
tmp2.click();
```

But I tried

```
('plusbtnmid').item(0) and ('ms-wow zoomInUp').item(0)
```

Nothing happened.

Could anybody please help?

Comment: What is `('plusbtnmid')`? If you want to call a function, you are required to access it through the function name, like in mathematics, e.g `f(x) = x + 1` for an incremental function, so I would call `f(1)` to get 2, so provide the full code to avoid confusion. Anyway, nothing happened because `.click()` is a jQuery method. If you are using jQuery, `$(".plusbtnmid").click()` will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to click that + button on document load, that be achieved by using this Jquery Click() function.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".ms-bounce").click(); // Trigger the Plus Button with the class name inside the image tag.
});
```

I used this piece of code which i have got through browser inspect element.

```
<img data-target="#plusbtnpop" data-toggle="modal" class="ms-bounce" src="images/plusicon.png" alt="..">
```